# Make pygame rectangle disappear when ball collides

Tags: python, pygame

So I'm doing a brick breaker game using Pygame. I want that everytime the ball hits a brick, that brick disappears (idk how)
Here's my code:

```
  bricks_list = [brick := Brick(6, 350, brick_width,brick_height,0),
brick := Brick(76, 350, brick_width,brick_height,0)] # A list of the bricks (rectangles)

#with a class (Brick) that I made

    for BRICK in bricks_list:
    brick_rect = pygame.Rect(BRICK.x, BRICK.y, brick.width, BRICK.height)
    if ball_rect.colliderect(brick_rect):
        yVel *= -1
        brick_break(bricks_list, BRICK) #function that I made (it does "bricks_list.remove(BRICK)")
    else:
        brick_rectangle = pygame.draw.rect(screen, LEVELS[BRICK.level], brick_rect)
```

If it can help, the problem is, when the ball collide with any of the bricks, that brick disappears ONLY when the ball is still colliding with it